# MySQL Operator: Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: The operator cannot be installed in the 'default' namespace

Tags: mysql, installation, kubernetes

I'm following the instructions on [ArtifactHub for `mysql-operator/mysql-operator`](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/mysql-operator/mysql-operator?modal=install).

```
helm install my-mysql-operator mysql-operator/mysql-operator --version 2.0.4
```

But I'm getting the error

> Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: execution error at (mysql-operator/templates/service_account_operator.yaml:3:5): Please provide a namespace with `-n`/`--namespace` . The operator cannot be installed in the 'default' namespace

What can I do to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MySQL installation instructions on ArtifactHub are incomplete, instead follow the official documentations on [Install using Helm Charts](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-operator/en/mysql-operator-installation-helm.html) which are currently documented as,

```shell
helm install my-mysql-operator mysql-operator/mysql-operator \
  --namespace mysql-operator --create-namespace
```

You have to specify the namespace with `-n` or `--namespace` and if it's not created you'll have to either create it or use `--create-namespace`